# How to append binary data to a specific node at a specific place in an XML file

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq-to-xml

We are using XML file to save our data which is all double. Since our data is very huge, in the range of GBs therefore we are converting it to byte in order to save disk space and access times. Also, we are writing our data in chunks of few MBs and that too the new chunk of data can come from same source as its previous one or from a different source. For each new source we have created an element in the XML file in order to identify the data from that source easily in future.
The problem that we are facing is that, how to identify the element corresponding to a source in XML file and then append the data corresponding to that source to the data already captured in the XML file. I am using Linq to XML and was not able to google any solution using this method. I tried XMLWriter class but the problem using that is how to identify or reach to the element for which I want to write the chunk.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "converting it to byte"? That's what every stream will do too.

Answer (score 1):

XML is not a good format for writing large amounts of binary data (due to need to store binary data as Base64 string or some other string-safe encoding) and also not good for updating chunks of data in the middle of large document. I'd recommend to reconsider your file format.

If you have to go with XML:

- make sure your byte arrays are Base64 encoded when written to XML
- you have to copy XML when you want to insert data in the middle. Consider using XmlReader and XmlWriter. Copy source XML up to the point where you want to add data, add data to output writer, and than finish copying remaining portion of XML.
- avoid loading whole XML in memory as it lilky will cause problmes with your GB range of data.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure I don't have the full picture here, but it is hard to understand why you don't use a database for this.  Nevertheless, to follow up on Alexei's post, here is a contrived example of how you could use XmlReader and XmlWriter to accomplish what I think you want to do:

```
//start with some dummy data
string bigData = "<bigdata><rec id='1'>1234</rec><rec id='2'>2468</rec></bigdata>";
string criterion = "2";
string append = "10";
string newValue = "";
bool match = false;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(sb))
{
    using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(bigData)))
    {
    while (reader.Read())
    {
    switch (reader.NodeType)
    {
    case XmlNodeType.Element:
        if (reader.LocalName == "rec")
        {
            match = reader.GetAttribute("id").ToString() == criterion;
        }
        writer.WriteStartElement(reader.LocalName);
        writer.WriteAttributes(reader, true);
        if (reader.IsEmptyElement)
        {
            writer.WriteEndElement();
        }
        break;
    case XmlNodeType.Text: // do the append here
        newValue = match ? reader.Value + append : reader.Value;
        writer.WriteString(newValue);
        break;
    //other cases based on node types
    case XmlNodeType.EndElement:
        writer.WriteFullEndElement();
        break;
    }                                                                      
    }
        writer.Flush();
        string x = sb.ToString();//output
    }                         
}
```